# SQL Select TOP 1 for each group in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good morning,

I want to alter my query in such a way, that only the top 1, filtered from h.started asc is selected.

```
select h.started, *  from wshhistory h
join asset a on h.assetid = a.uid
inner join 
(
    select Count(*) as TotalLatest, a.uid, a.deleted from asset a
    join wshhistory h on a.uid = h.assetid
    where h.latest = 1 
    group by a.uid, a.deleted
    having Count(*) > 1
) X
on X.uid = h.assetid
where X.deleted = 0 and h.latest = 1
order by h.assetid desc
```

I searched all over, and found in most posts, to use:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.uid ORDER BY h.started asc) as rn
```

But I can't seem to use this since I need use group by, and this results in the error message:

> Column 'wshhistory.started' is invalid in the select list because it
>   is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY
>   clause.

---

To give some extra info about my query:
I need to search where I have duplicates of Latest = 1 (table: wshhistory), of the same assetid.  And then I need to set the them all on 0 except the latest one.

Comment: add where rownum()=1 at the inner join

Comment: @BasilBattikhi huh??? The OP is trying to use ROW_NUMBER. Not sure what your comment is suggesting but you can't use a window function in the where clause.

Comment: @SeanLange LOl you are right seems that i got a mistake

Comment: @SeanLange what do you suggest ?

Comment: I would suggest that the OP give us some data to work with and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
with toupdate as (
      select h.*,
             row_number() over (partition by h.assetid order by h.started desc) as seqnum
      from wshhistory h
      where h.latest = 1
     )
update toupdate
    set latest = 0
    where seqnum > 1 and
          exists (select 1
                  from asset a
                  where a.uid = toupdate.assetid and a.deleted = 0
                 );
```

Sample data and desired results are much easier to work with than non-working queries.

Comment: Thats it, thanks! I'll keep in mind to provide sample data.